# How to call `setText` on multiple JTextfields?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, boilerplate

I want to figure out a way to set the text for multiple `JTextfield`s in just a few lines (preferable one line) of code rather than a new line for every textfield.

I am looking for a way to invoke the `setText` method on multiple `JTextfield` values. My code works correctly, but I do not want to write out `someField.setText("0.00");` for each `JTextfield`.

Here is code with the repeated calls that I want to shorten:

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Clear");
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(367, 533, 86, 32);
    btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            textIncome.setText("0.00");
            textGrossSalary.setText("0.00");
            textGrossSalary.setText("0.00");
            textHousehold.setText("0.00");
            textFood.setText("0.00");
            textChildren.setText("0.00");
            textBills.setText("0.00");
            textIncidentals.setText("0.00");
            textCredit.setText("0.00");
            textHome.setText("0.00");
            textInvestings.setText("0.00");
            textPets.setText("0.00");
            textTransport.setText("0.00");
            textLifestyle.setText("0.00");
            textTax.setText("0.00");
            textDisposable.setText("0.00");
            textHealthFitness.setText("0.00");
            textGiftsDonations.setText("0.00");

        }

    });
```

Comment: You can use reflection i think.

Comment: Your question has collected a few close votes; I edited your question so that future readers will be less likely to close vote. If you don't like any of my changes, feel free to [edit] them however you like. You can see the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30588155/revisions) for past changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them in a `List` or an array and iterate over them

For example, create an instance field array which contains the fields which you want to set (to the same value)

```
private JTextField fields[] = new JTextField[]{
        textIncome,
        textGrossSalary,
        textGrossSalary,
        textHousehold,
        textFood,
        textChildren,
        textBills,
        textIncidentals,
        textCredit,
        textHome,
        textInvestings,
        textPets,
        textTransport,
        textLifestyle,
        textTax,
        textDisposable,
        textHealthFitness,
        textGiftsDonations};
```

Then when the `ActionListener` is triggered, iterate over it...

```
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (JTextField field : fields) {
            field.setText("0.00");
        }
    }
});
```

Based on `btnNewButton_1.setBounds(367, 533, 86, 32);`, I'd advise avoiding using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I guessed that would be a good idea. But how do you put a JTextfield into an array? I thought you need normal data types.

Comment: An array can contain any data type, primitives or objects.  You declare it like any array `{Type}[] name = new {Type}[{size}];` for example

Comment: @BrianN Nope! You can store anything you want in an array. Just do `JTextField [] fields = new JTextField[num];`. Or use an ArrayList and do `ArrayList<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();`